# not able to access child component of parent inside controller

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

i have container named `maincontainer` in which there are three components

1. Button   `(whose id is mainBtn)`
2. textfield
3. textfield

now when i try to access the child component `mainBtn` of `maincontainer` to `setText` dynamically i am getting either `undefine`on `setText` method of object is not define.

so that means code inside my controller is not able to access the child component.

here what i have tried but non of them are working , i am accessing using reference in controller. `mymaincontainer : 'maincontainer'`

```
   this.getMyMainContainer().getComponent('mainBtn'); -- undefined

   this.getMyMainContainer().down('#mainBtn'); -- null

   this.getMyMainContainer().getItems()[0]  -- undefined
```

Comment: try " this.getMymaincontainer().getComponent('mainBtn'); "

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.getMyMainContainer().getComponent().getItems().get('mainBtn');
```